# Static analysis tool customization for any language

Tags: static-analysis

We are using a Tool in our project. This tool has its own language which is similar to Java. I am looking for a static analysis tool which can be applied to the new language. 
Are there any static analysis tools which can be customized to any languages? or Is there any document or any reference on how to develop the static analysis tool for our own languages?

Thanks.

Comment: "static analysis" can mean anything from computing the ratio of comment lines to code lines to making sure that the code can never raise an uncaught exception when run. You should specify what kind of static analysis you are interested in.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you really want, [Rascal](http://www.rascal-mpl.org/) may help:

> Rascal is a domain specific language for source code analysis and manipulation a.k.a. meta-programming.

Answer (score 2):

The [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is an infrastructure for building program analysis tools, both static and dynamic.   DMS also has a large number of front end for widely uses languages and their dialects (C, C++, Java, C#, COBOL, Fortran, ...)

If your langauge is a lot like Java, you'd likely be able to easily build a dialect of the existing Java front end that covered your language.   From that point you could build a static analysis tool of your choice.

Static analysis is a pretty broad topic.  In general, to do it you need to know how information flows in your program: control flow, data flow, pointer anlaysis, call graphs, etc.  DMS provides infrastructure for implementing all that; again, you may be able to modify the implementation for Java.